# Surjective function on a compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

Assume $f:K\rightarrow K$, is surjective and $K$ is a compact metric space and we have $d(f(x),f(y))\leq d(x,y)\, \forall x,y\in K$. How can I prove that $d(f(x),f(y))= d(x,y)\, \forall x,y\in K$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried assuming otherwise. I was thinking that $diam(f(K))$ could be proved to be less than $diam(K)$, but didn't get any good results.

Comment: I also know $f$ is equi-continuous.